# CoreData, NSArraycontroler and NSTable, NSTable does not update after object added

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

Still learning so I could really use some help from you more seasoned folks. I'm learning more about the MVC model and trying to implement this with CoreData. My test application has the `AppDeligate`, MainController and a MocManager. All `CoreData` stuff is moved to the MocManager.

On the xib I have an `NSTable`, an `NSArrayController` and a `NSButton`.

In MainController, I have an instance of the MocController with a simple method to add a name to the database.

```
-(IBAction) addPerson:(id)sender{ [manager addperson:@"Sam"]; }
```

This method is called when the NSButton is pressed. Pressing the NSButton does add the name to the database, however it does not update the table. If I close the App and reopen, the name will appear in the NSTable, so the adding method is good and is working.

I tried both of the following (Separately):

1. Linked the `NSArrayController` to MainController through an `IBOutlet`
2. Linking the `NSArrayController` to MocManager through an `IBOutlet`

In both cases, I used [ArrayController rearrangeObjects] method after the save - the `NSTable` still does not update.

--[EDIT]----

Appears to be a bindings issues as pointed out by Vadian - but I cannot seem to figure out where/why.

In a previous App I successfully moved the `coredata` stack in to the MainController, all bindings appear to be working properly.

For this test App, I moved the `coredata` stack to it's own controller - "MocManager".

In MainController I created an instance of MocManager with:

```
MocManager* Manager; //This is in .h

manager = [[MocManager alloc] init]; //This is in .m init method
```

Data loads in to table on startup, but will not sync when using addPerson method in MainController.

Also, I connected an NSButton directly to the `remove` method on the `NSArrayController` - the items are removed from the `NSTable` but not saved, they reappear when App restarted. This all further points to the bindings issue.

Any pointers/thoughts/help would be greatly appreciated.

--[EDIT - SOLUTION]-----
Thanks to Vadian for pointing me in the right direction, it was in fact my bindings.
In the `NSArrayController` in the XIB I needed to bind it properly to the correct `ManagedObjectContext`. In my case it is to manager.ManagedObjectContext.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: You have to use Cocoa Bindings (the array controller must be bound to the moc and the entity) to get automatic update. Otherwise you have to explicitly add the object also to the array controller.

Comment: @vadian: Thanks for the comment, I believe I did this, in `NSArrayController` in object controller I bound to `Entity Name` and in `Parameters` linked to MocManager using Model Key Path 'managedObjectContext'. Then through an `IBOutlet` bound to MocController in order to use 'rearrangeObjects'. Did I miss one somewhere?

Comment: If the bindings are set up correctly you don't need `rearrangeObjects` at all

Comment: I believe the preferred method would be to use a NSFetchedResultsController https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: @pds Why is `NSFetchedResultsController` preferred over `NSArrayController`?

Comment: @Willeke It's not preferred per se. If your design widely relies on Cocoa Bindings `NSArrayController` is the better choice.

Comment: Please add your "[EDIT - SOLUTION]" as an actual Answer; don't edit it into your question.